# CodeIgniter 4 va lento sin realizar consultas sql

Tags: php, framework, codeingiter

Buenaas, entro despues de un poco tiempo a ver mi pagina web, me di cuenta que mi pagina realizada en CodeIgniter 4 va lentisimo, demora 5 segundos en mostrar una vista, la consulta que hago para mostrar datos en mi pagina es de tan solo 5 columnas y con 6 a 10 registros.
No entiendo porque, incluso pasa cuando ingreso al login, ahi ni si quiera realizo una consulta.
He hecho un checkout de versiones anteriores para ver si quizá agregue alguna funcion que haga lenta la pagina, pero el problema persiste, normalmente mi pagina cargaba super rapido.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el index donde supuestamente va lento

```
index.php
<?php

// Check PHP version.
$minPhpVersion = '7.4'; // If you update this, don't forget to update 
`spark`.
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, $minPhpVersion, '<')) {
   $message = sprintf(
    'Your PHP version must be %s or higher to run CodeIgniter. 
Current version: %s',
    $minPhpVersion,
    PHP_VERSION
  );

  exit($message);
 }

 // Path to the front controller (this file)
 define('FCPATH', __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

// Ensure the current directory is pointing to the front controller's 
directory
chdir(FCPATH);

/*
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* BOOTSTRAP THE APPLICATION
*---------------------------------------------------------------
* This process sets up the path constants, loads and registers
* our autoloader, along with Composer's, loads our constants
* and fires up an environment-specific bootstrapping.
*/

 // Load our paths config file
 // This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your 
 folder structure.
 require FCPATH . './app/Config/Paths.php';
 // ^^^ Change this line if you move your application folder

 $paths = new Config\Paths();

 // Location of the framework bootstrap file.
require rtrim($paths->systemDirectory, '\\/ ') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 
'bootstrap.php';

// Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV
require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php';
(new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load();

/*
* ---------------------------------------------------------------
* GRAB OUR CODEIGNITER INSTANCE
* ---------------------------------------------------------------
*
* The CodeIgniter class contains the core functionality to make
* the application run, and does all of the dirty work to get
* the pieces all working together.
*/

$app = Config\Services::codeigniter();
$app->initialize();
$context = is_cli() ? 'php-cli' : 'web';
$app->setContext($context);

 /*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * Now that everything is setup, it's time to actually fire
 * up the engines and make this app do its thang.
 */

 $app->run();
```

Comment: es un server privado o un vps compartido, esoo puede afectar mas que los cambios del codigo